# How to create an additional column in a SQL query that contains the number of rows with a column value equal to a column value from the current row?

Tags: sql, oracle-apex, calculated-columns

This is what I currently have (it doesn't work):

```
select MOCKSTEMS.WORD_ID,
       MOCKSTEMS.STEM_ID,
       MOCKSTEMS.LABSTEM,
       MOCKSTEMS.LABSTEMCATEGORY,
       MOCKLEMMAS.LEMMAFORM,
       MOCKSTEMS.LEMMA_ID,
       MOCKWORDS.ORIGINALWORD,
       MOCKSTEMS.CONTAINEDIN,
       COUNT(*) as SAMEVALUE from MOCKSTEMS where CONTAINEDIN=STEM_ID
from MOCKSTEMS
inner join MOCKWORDS on MOCKSTEMS.WORD_ID = MOCKWORDS.WORD_ID
inner join MOCKLEMMAS on MOCKSTEMS.LEMMA_ID = MOCKLEMMAS.LEMMA_ID
```

Basically, I wish to create a column called 'SAMEVALUE' that shows the number of rows in this query with 'CONTAINEDIN' values equal to the 'STEM_ID' value of each row. Is this possible, and if so, how can I do it with SQL?

EDITED:

This is what I get when I run the query without the 'COUNT(*) as SAMEVALUE from MOCKSTEMS where CONTAINEDIN=STEM_ID' row:
[image of a few rows returned by the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQFDM.png).

For example, for the row with STEM_ID='stem-003' and LABSTEM='owotan okitz', I would like the SAMEVALUE column to have value 2, because there are 2 rows with CONTAINEDIN='stem-003', as [circled in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGkke.png).

It would also be fine if the SAMEVALUE column just indicates true/false (or 0/1) depending on whether there are rows with CONTAINEDIN values equal to the STEM_ID of each row.

Comment: what is your RDBMS ?

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result. It seems I misunderstood what you need.

Comment: @VenkataramanR I'm using Oracle APEX.

Comment: @TheImpaler I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

To get overall count alongside the query results, you need an analytic function. So to count only rows with some condition, we put this condition in `case` expression, which returns something in case of "true", and null in other cases. Then `count` will ignore nulls.

```
select MOCKSTEMS.WORD_ID,
       MOCKSTEMS.STEM_ID,
       MOCKSTEMS.LABSTEM,
       MOCKSTEMS.LABSTEMCATEGORY,
       MOCKLEMMAS.LEMMAFORM,
       MOCKSTEMS.LEMMA_ID,
       MOCKWORDS.ORIGINALWORD,
       MOCKSTEMS.CONTAINEDIN,
       COUNT(
         case
           when CONTAINEDIN=STEM_ID
           then 1
         end
       ) over() as SAMEVALUE
       /*Over is empty to consider all the result set as a single window*/
from MOCKSTEMS
inner join MOCKWORDS on MOCKSTEMS.WORD_ID = MOCKWORDS.WORD_ID
inner join MOCKLEMMAS on MOCKSTEMS.LEMMA_ID = MOCKLEMMAS.LEMMA_ID
```